# Filtering a Form Array in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, forms, typescript, formarray

I have a list which I transform into a FormArray to generate a list of buttons in html. I want to filter the cars by name

**CarComponent.html**

```
  <input #searchBox id="search-box" (input)="search(searchBox.value)" />

<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="showCars">
              <input type="button" class ="btn"  formArrayName="carsList" *ngFor="let car of carsList$ | async; let i = index" value="{{carsList[i].name}}" >
        </form>
```

**CarComponent.ts**

```
 carsList$: Observable<Car[]>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();
  search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }

constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder,...)
{
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      carsList: new FormArray([])
    });

this.addButtons();

}

 ngOnInit() {
    this.spinner.show(); 
    this.carsList$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((term:string)=> 
      this.carsList ??? // Is this correct ?? What do I put here ?
    )




  }

  private addButtons() {

      this.carsList.map((o,i)=>{
        const control = new FormControl;
        (this.form.controls.carsList as FormArray).push(control);
      })
    }

export const CarsList: Car[] = [
  { name: 'Mercedes' },
  { name: 'BMW' },
  { name: 'Porsche' },
  { name: 'Cadillac' }
]
```

So I would like to know how to do the filtering correctly, without using pipe for performance reasons.

Comment: why do you use a FormArray? A FormArray is used if we has an array of "inputs", not a series of "buttons"

Comment: is `this.carsList ???` actually `this.carsList$`

Just to understand right: You want to `const CarList` filtered according to the supplied searchTerm and then generate buttons for every car found?

Comment: Arikael, yes. I want to filter CarsList which contains all the cars. CarList$ is an observable which will contain the filtered cars.